# How to install spark-xml library using dbx

Tags: databricks, apache-spark-xml, databricks-dbx

I am trying to install library `spark-xml_2.12-0.15.0` using `dbx`.

The documentation I found is to include it on the `conf/deployment.yml` file like:

```
custom:
  basic-cluster-props: &basic-cluster-props
    spark_version: "10.4.x-cpu-ml-scala2.12"

  basic-static-cluster: &basic-static-cluster
    new_cluster:
      <<: *basic-cluster-props
    num_workers: 2

build:
    commands:
        - "mvn clean package" #


environments:
  default:
    workflows:
      - name: "charming-aurora-sample-jvm"
        libraries:
          - jar: "{{ 'file://' + dbx.get_last_modified_file('target/scala-2.12', 'jar') }}" #

        tasks:
          - task_key: "main"
            <<: *basic-static-cluster
            deployment_config: #

              no_package: true
            spark_jar_task:
                main_class_name: "org.some.main.ClassName"
```

You may see documentation page here: https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/jvm/jvm_devops/?h=maven

I have installed the library on the cluster using Maven file (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml_2.13/0.15.0):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-xml_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>0.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I can use it on a notebook level but not from a job deployed using dbx.

### Edit

I am using PySpark .

So, I included it as this at `conf/deployment.yml`:

```
libraries:
    - maven: "com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.15.0"
```

On the file `conf/deployment.yml`

```
- name: "my-job"
  libraries:
    - maven: 
      - coordinates:"com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.15.0"
  tasks:
    - task_key: "first_task"
      <<: *basic-static-cluster
      python_wheel_task:
        package_name: "project_name"
        entry_point: "jl" # take a look at the setup.py entry_points section for details on how to define an entrypoint
        parameters: ["--conf-file", "file:fuse://conf/tasks/my_job_config.yml"]
```

Then I go with

```
dbx deploy my-job
```

This throwing the following error:

```
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://adb-xxxx.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/reset
 Response from server:
 { 'error_code': 'MALFORMED_REQUEST',
  'message': "Could not parse request object: Expected 'START_OBJECT' not "
             "'START_ARRAY'\n"
             ' at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 91]\n'
             ' at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@37fda06f; line: 1, '
             'column: 91]'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, and the error you've run into doesn't really say much.
We plan to introduce structure verification to make such that checks are more understandable.

The correct deployment file structure should look as follows:

```yaml
- name: "my-job"
  tasks:
    - task_key: "first_task"
      <<: *basic-static-cluster
      # please note that libraries section is on the task level 
      libraries:
        - maven: 
            coordinates:"com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.15.0"
      python_wheel_task:
        package_name: "project_name"
        entry_point: "jl" # take a look at the setup.py entry_points section for details on how to define an entrypoint
        parameters: ["--conf-file", "file:fuse://conf/tasks/my_job_config.yml"]
```

Two important points here:

1. `libraries` section is on the task level
2. `maven` section expects an object, not a list, therefore this will not work:

```yaml
#THIS IS INCORRECT DON'T DO THIS
libraries:
  - maven: 
      - coordinates:"com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.15.0"
```

But this will:

```yaml
# correct structure
libraries:
  - maven: 
      coordinates:"com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.15.0"
```

I've summarized these detail in [this new documentation section](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/general/dependency_management/).

Comment: It was really close. With the code you provided I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://dbx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/deployment/) says following:

> The workflows section of the deployment file fully follows the [Databricks Jobs API structures](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html).

If you look into [API documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsSubmit), you will see that you need to use `maven` instead of `file`, and provide Maven coordinate as a string. Something like this (please note that you need to use Scala 2.12, not 2.13):

```
libraries:
  - maven: 
      coordinates: "com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.15.0"
```

Comment: It did not work. I edited the question. Could it be because I am using pyspark?

Comment: Ah, I've used the wrong YAML representation - this one should work

Comment: I updated the deployment.yml file and get a new error. (I updated the question with the error)

Comment: sorry again, can you try to remove `-` from coordinates...

Comment: Did not work either.